# How do I resolve a to-many saving conflict in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, merge

Here's my relationship setup:

`Section < ----- >> Article`

I'm doing much parsing on multiple threads using the thread confinement strategy (gross, I know, but legacy; changing the strategy right now is not an option).

I get merge conflicts when I examine the `NSMergeConflict` object though I'm not seeing the to-many relationship `NSManagedObjectID` that [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSMergeConflict_Class/) promises, so I'm confused and wondering how to get at them.

I'm creating my `NSMergePolicy` subclass like this:

```
class ModelMergePolicy: NSMergePolicy {
    init() {
        super.init(mergeType: .MergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)
    }
}
```

I chose `MergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType` because merging the other properties (which are simple attributes) should be easy and handled automagically.

Is there anything else I need to do to see the to-many relationship object IDs in the conflict list in my `resolveConflicts(list:error:)` override?

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

In frustration, I read the documentation more closely, and it seems to imply that to-many relationships need to be fetched and there won't be any `NSManagedObjectID`s to do fetching with, which makes sense to me.

What I'm stuck on now is how to get a specific version of a to-many relationship (or `NSManagedObject` to get the relationship out of) so I can do what I need to do to handle the merge.

Comment: Why does `ModelMergePolicy` exist?

Comment: @TomHarrington Because any merge policy I was using previously had resulted in a save conflict.